# I'm trying to download Laravel 9, but version 5.4 is what I get

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, version, laravel-9

I'm trying to install Laravel for first time, and I want to install version 9, so I follow steps in the documentation:
composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app
cd example-app
php artisan serve

but then when I check the version, I find that its 5.4.36
and I can't find a way to upgrade it.
Note: I already have PHP 8 , MYSQL and Composer.

Comment: "when I check the verstion" - how do you do that? What else did you do to resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

laravel/installer is a CLI tool for the init laravel project. and this cmd globally installed that CLI tool in the system. after that laravel new project-name init a project.

```
composer global require laravel/installer
 
laravel new example-app
 
cd example-app
 
php artisan serve
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: laravel/installer is a CLI tool for the init laravel project. and this cmd globally installed that CLI tool in the system. after that laravel new project-name init a project.

Comment: Please add **all** clarification to your answer by editing it

Comment: I have, if you found it useful vote for it.

Answer (score 0):

The 5.4.36 that you get, is the version of Laravel Installer.
if you Run php artisan --version in your folder where you installed your project you will be able to see your laravel framework version. Which should be 9.

if not try this code:
composer create-project laravel/laravel first-laravel9

Answer (score 0):

Because you checked Laravel global installer version that responsible for install the full packages and laravel app, you run this command:

> `laravel --version`

But If you want to check laravel app first install laravel app and go to the project and check the version by this commands:

> `laravel new example_app`

> `cd example_app`

> `php artisan --version`